# How to count grouped records that match multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

i have three tables

table 1; product table with product_name, product_id, product price

table 2; store table with store_id, store_name

table 3; stock table with id, store_id, product_id, sock, min_stock

i need to sum the stock of each product as total_stock and also sum the min_stock of each product as total_min_stock.
I should then count the number of products whose total_stock value is less than total_min_stock as low_stock_number and echo the value of low_stock_number

Comment: You should first try to implement it yourself and then ask specific question if you have problem. Show your first implementation and then you have better probability that you get some review or advice. My advice - try to express SQL to get at least processable result - use PHP to process the result and present it to a user.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each table's unique value is its id, what you need is to aum and group by, using HAVING to condition the GROUPed results

```
SELECT
 p.product_id,
 SUM(IFNULL(st.stock,0) as total_stock,
 SUM(IFNULL(st.min_stock,0) as total_min_stock
FROM
 product p
 LEFT JOIN stock st ON st.product_id = st.product_id
GROUP BY
 p.product_id
HAVING
  total_stock < total_min_stock
```

Comment: miss typing of an alias, should be st in all cases and not sr in what of them. thanks